# Obj C and makeObjectsPerformSelector - am I overlooking something?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

being still kinda new to obj-c, I was playing around with the makeObjectsPerformSelector method.

I have two arrays containing UISteppers and UITextfields respectively:

```
_stepper = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
           _stepMa, _stepMafree, _stepDe,   _stepDefree,   _stepFl, _stepFlfree,
           _stepEn, _stepEnfree, _stepEnBl, _stepEnBlfree, _stepVo, _stepVofree,
           _stepVe, _stepVefree, _stepIn,   _stepInfree,   _stepOt, _stepOtfree,
           _stepIn170, _stepIn170free, _stepZy, _stepZyfree,
           nil];

_fields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
           _MaFeld, _MaFeldfree, _DeFeld,   _DeFeldfree,   _FlFeld, _FlFeldfree,
           _EnFeld, _EnFeldfree, _EnBlFeld, _EnBlFeldfree, _VoFeld, _VoFeldfree,
           _VeFeld, _VeFeldfree, _InFeld,   _InFeldfree,   _OtFeld, _OtFeldfree,
           _InFeld170, _InFeld170free, _ZyFeld, _ZyFeldfree,
           nil];
```

In some method I want to reset them:

```
- (void) resetFields
{
    [_stepper enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(UIStepper* stepper, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         stepper.value = 0;
     }];

    [_fields enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(UITextField* field, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         field.text = @"0";
     }];
}
```

which works as expected.

trying to shorten that code a bit I tried my luck with the mentioned method:

```
- (void) resetFields
{
    [_stepper makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(value) withObject:0];
    [_fields  makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(text)  withObject:@"0"];
}
```

which had no effect... I guess there is something I did not consider, but what?

Thanks!

Comment: the setter is the selector you need to perform, e.g. `–setText:` or `–setValue:`, but that `–makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` won't work with `–setValue:` regarding the expected value is a _primitive_ rather than an _object_

Comment: Aaah! Wasn't aware of that. Tahnks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To bypass the problem of int to be a C type and not an object, use KVC (Key-Value Coding). If you call setValue:forKey: on a NSArray object, the method setValue:forKey: is call on each of the objects of the array. And with a bonus, KVC is managing all the primitive stuff.

```
[_stepper setValue:@0 forKey:@"value"];
[_fields setValue:@"0" forKey:@"text"];
```

Answer (score 3):

`performSelector` calls (all kinds of them) can only take Objective-C objects (ones that can be represented by `id` type). C types like `double`, `BOOL`, `int` etc. will not work, so you can not set `value` this way unless you change its type to `NSNumber*`.

For setting `text` property, you need to use `setText:` selector; `text` is the getter. Since this property type is Objective-C class `NSString`, performSelector will work.

Comment: Argh, thanks for that hint - stupid me; just assumed instead of thought (because .value also worked for setting the UIStepper value).